# Does Serialization have anything to do with preventing buttons, links and such from being clicked twice?

Tags: java, php, http, serialization

I understood that Serializable means the data can gets convered into 1s and 0s so its availabe to be streamed to web services etc but someone told me that Serialization is also used for preventing data being sent twice if a user accidently double clicks a link for example. is this true

edit: im talking about Serializable class in java

Comment: @user521180, both @saugata and @cherouvim seem to be correct, from the look of things. I must admit I don't deal with HTTP much myself, but the Serializable _keyword_ is definitely used for converting data to 1s and 0s. From @cherouvim's comment it seems there is also a technique to do with processing HTTP which is called serializing, which is _nothing_to_do_ with the Java keyword Serializable. I hope that's clear!

Comment: Oops, I didn't mean keyword, I meant Interface!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's true. This means serializing http request processing from the same user. In Java webapps this is usually done by synchronizing processing on the HttpSession or on an Object stored in the session acting as a [mutex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion).

Some frameworks do this out of the box. For example Spring MVC does this in the http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/AbstractController.html:

> synchronizeOnSession: whether the call to handleRequestInternal should be synchronized around the HttpSession, to serialize invocations from the same client. No effect if there is no HttpSession.

This solves concurrency issues in the HttpSession which is best described in the classic article by Brian Goetz [Java theory and practice: Are all stateful Web applications broken?](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp09238.html)

Comment: I think you are talking of serialization as in one after another, the question is about java serialization as in java.io.Serializable

Answer (score 0):

No.
Also, webservices is a completely different area.